# Cairo Arabic font issue in Aspose.pdf

Tags: vb.net, arabic, aspose.pdf

I am using Aspose.pdf for vb.net to convert my data to .pdf file.
File contains Arabic Characters and is using **Cairo font.**
The generated pdf file not display any Arabic words!

How can I solve this issue?

[image]

Comment: This is something you should contact Aspose support for. I'll bet that you're likely using a Latin-only subset of the Cairo typeface (because font-files with _all_ characters from most writing systems like Arabic, Chinese and Japanese will balloon the font's installed size).

Comment: Is your PDF a "drawing-only" PDF (where structured text is not preserved, instead text is rendered like vector art), or as a Tagged PDF where the original text is preserved (and also selectable, etc)? You need to use a PDF Inspector to see what's inside the final output PDF so you can see if the problem is just a font subset issue, or something else (e.g. bad Unicode encoding, causing your text to be dropped entirely or misinterpreted).